# When is this complex function continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2 + i}{z^2 + 1}.$$
When is $f$ continuous?
I tried rationalising it and considering the Riemann-Cauchy equations, but it seems to be a lot of algebra work. Is there a fast way to do it?
I know that since it's composed of continuous functions, it'd be continuous, but I'm iffy at $z = \pm i$. How would I show that at $z = \pm i$, it is either continuous or not continuous?

Comment: This is a function from where to where?

Comment: Not sure, the question was given as it was.

Comment: If the target space is $\mathbb{C}$ the domain must exclude $z=\pm i$. A continuous function must be defined at the point. But as a function from the Riemann sphere to the Riemann sphere it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: There is no need to use CR equations: the usual differentiation rules hold for complex valued functions and this one is differentiable wherever it's defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is a quotient of two polynomials (which are of course continuous everywhere)

Hence the only points of discontinuity are the zeros of the denominator, i.e. $\pm i.$

Comment: Is there a way to define $f$ differently at $\pm i$ to make it continuous?

Comment: No, not in the complex numbers, since there the function approaches infinity.

Comment: This would only be the case if $|f|$ is bounded in a n.b.h.d of $+i$ or $-i$. It's easy to check that this isn't the case.

Comment: In my estimation, we may speak of a function being discontinuous only at a point where it is defined. For instance, the reciprocal function $f(t)=1/t$ for $t\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is continuous. Zero is a point of nondefinition, not a point of discontinuity. If we say that a function is discontinuous where not defined, what are we to do with the real function $\sqrt{t\,}\,$?

Comment: @Lubin So it is most accurate to say that the original $f$ is continuous throughout its domain since it isn't even defined at $\pm i$?

Comment: Precisely right.

Answer (score 3):

The function is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}-\{-i,\;i\}$ since the Cauchy-Riemann condition is satisfied. Holomorphic implies continuity, thus it is verified. In $\pm i$ the function is not defined so it makes no sense talking of continuity.
Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) the general definition reads

> The function f is *continuous* at some point $c$ **of its domain**...

Plug $z=x+iy$ in the given function. We get
$$\frac{x^2+2 i x y-y^2+i}{x^2+2 i x y-y^2+1}$$
Then we verify that ${i{\partial f \over \partial x}}={\partial f \over \partial y}$

${\partial f \over \partial x}=\frac{(2-2 i) (x+i y)}{\left(1+(x+i y)^2\right)^2}$

${\partial f \over \partial y}=\frac{(2+2 i) (x+i y)}{\left(1+(x+i y)^2\right)^2}$

Comment: Thank you; but I presume that this doesn't always work (to find points of discontinuity) since we could have more points of continuity in comparison to amount of points to be holomorphic?